# creating possible combinations list from Many to Many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Set of tables

`Hotels` 
`Countries` 
`Regions` 
`Cities`
`Hotel_Types`

and a many to many relations table named `Mappings` which contains all the relations/mappings which contains info like

```
id, hotel_id, reference_type, reference_id, ...
```

where `reference_type` can be a `Country`, `Region`, `City`, `Hotel_Type` etc
and  `reference_id` is the id of said entity like `country_id` or `city_id` etc.

I need to create a list of all possible combinations of

```
Country_Name+Hotel_Type_Name
Region_Name+Hotel_Type_Name
City_Name+Hotel_Type_Name
```

Where the hotels exist. Any help how may I access the names from different tables and how to combine them

Answer (score 0):

I am implying few things here but you could do inner joins in this way:

```
select name, hotel_type_name 
from (select c.country_name as name, h.hotel_type_name Mappings m inner join Countries c on m.reference_type='Country' and m.reference_id=c.country_id inner join hotel_Types h on m.reference_type='Hotel_type' and m.reference_id=h.hotel_type_id)  union all 
     (select c.region_name as name, h.hotel_type_name Mappings m inner join Regions r on m.reference_type='Region' and m.reference_id=r.region_id  inner join Hotel_Types h on m.reference_type='Hotel_type' and m.reference_id=h.hotel_type_id) union all
     (select c.city_name as name, h.hotel_type_name Mappings m inner join Cities ci on m.reference_type='City' and m.reference_id=ci.city_id inner join Hotel_Types h on m.reference_type='Hotel_type' and m.reference_id=h.hotel_type_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list unique combinations of `Country_Name+Hotel_Type_Name`

```
--link hotels to hotel_type
with Hotel_Hotel_Types as (
  select h.hotel_id
    ,ht.reference_id as hotel_types_id
  from Hotels as h
  inner join Mappings ht on ht.reference_type = 'Hotel_Type' and h.hotel_id = ht.hotel_id
)
--link hotels to Country_Name
,Hotel_Country_Name as (
  select h.hotel_id
    ,c.reference_id as countries_id
  from Hotels as h
  inner join Mappings c on c.reference_type = 'Country' and h.hotel_id = c.hotel_id
)
select distinct ht.*, c.*
from Hotel_Hotel_Types hht
  inner join Hotel_Types ht on ht.hotel_types_id = hht.hotel_types_id
  inner join Hotel_Country_Name hc on hc.hotel_id = hht.hotel_id
  inner join Countries c on с.countries_id = hc.countries_id
```

`Region_Name+Hotel_Type_Name` and `City_Name+Hotel_Type_Name` can be queried using similar sqls.